# OneDrive External Sharing Does not ask for access code

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive-for-business, external-users

We have a guest user with non-microsoft account. While sharing link with "new" guest user(with whom document has never shared in the tenant), it asks for "Send Code" and user can access successfully.

But the same document when shared with existing guest(who has previously accessed some content in SharePoint in same tenant using personal gmail account), when opening the document, it asks for logging in using Microsoft account and does not show option to "Send Code" like it does for new users.

How to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

If the recipient has a work or school account, they only need to enter the code the first time. Then they will be added as a guest and can sign in with their organization's user name and password.

If the recipient doesn't have a work or school account, they need to use a code each time they access the file or folder, and they are not added to your directory.

Since the gmail user has been a guest in this organization, they will not able to provide verification code.

Remove the user in Guest users and check the result.

[image]

Reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/external-sharing-overview

Comment: Thank you. But what is the solution for sharing to work with this account?

Comment: Please refer to the latest reply.